# Good online course recomendation for Topology

Tags: algebraic-topology, online-resources

I want to learn the field of topology from scratch. I am working on a self-project for classifying using neural networks based on topology statistics features. I am looking for recommendations for online free sources to learn the necessary fundamentals of topology for such a project. I do not mind diving as deep as required into the math. I am new to the subject.

Any good recommendations?

Comment: Tadashi tokieda lectures

Comment: Have you studied real analysis?

Comment: I don't believe your aspirations are realistic. Topology is a generalization of real analysis. Learning topology without analysis is like learning calculus without a knowledge of basic algebra.

Comment: I don't. I went to college and graduate school. I don't believe I would have been able to learn any advanced mathematics without a formal education but I am not the benchmark for what's doable.

Comment: I think the quickest way to learn a maths topic is to find a university you like and read its lecture notes. My personal recommendation would be to go here: https://courses-archive.maths.ox.ac.uk/overview/undergraduate#50879, and read the notes for Part A Topology, Part B Topology and Groups, Part C Algebraic Topology, and then the linked lecture slides for Part C Computational Algebraic Topology

Comment: You may be okay. It seems like you are more interested in network topologies which is very different from what would be taught in a topology course in the math department. Try to find a syllabus from a university course on topology. There may be a lot of material that you don't actually need for your project.